# How to implement events in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, events

The [Laravel Eloquent Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) docs give this example:

```
namespace App;

use App\Events\UserSaved;
use App\Events\UserDeleted;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The event map for the model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'saved' => UserSaved::class,
        'deleted' => UserDeleted::class,
    ];
}
```

I simply want to know what would go in a `UserSaved::class` to, let's say, add a hash id on the initial save. The docs are frustratingly opaque at this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any of your model event classes, just do this:

For example: **App\Events\UserSaved.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserSaved
{

    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var \App\User
     */
    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        // All dispatched model events will receive an instance
        // of the model itself. Usually, we'll just assign
        // it as a property of this event class
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Dispatched event are supplied with the model instance, as shown [in the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/039b565cc7c8f53de85de311e0a8b3fe9e008b92/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php#L165):

[Documentation: Defining Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-events)

So at the later time when your listeners caught this event, they will have an instance of this `UserSaved` object, and you can just access user from `$userSaved->user`.

Comment: Man, oh man. I hate it when docs leave out crucial but simple information!

Comment: Just crawl into the source code. It's not too cryptic to follow through. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It would be an event class, it takes the current model the event is being fired for in its constructor.

> "An event class is simply a data container which holds the information related to the event. " [Laravel 5.5 Docs - Events - Defining Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-events)

You will need to setup a listener to listen for your custom event object you are now firing instead of the eloquent string event it would normally fire. In the listener(s) you can react to this event.